# Launch iOS application as a popup

Tags: ios

I want to Launch my iOS app in a small screen as oppose to open in full screen mode. Is there any way to override launch screen default parameters to open in a small screen like a popup ?

Comment: no, you cannot do that on iOS. Apps take full screen context

Comment: In the future, if apple allows something like this, you can do it -- like Small apps in Sony Xperia. Currently you **cannot** do it in iOS.

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me.

Comment: ya why downvote ? I want to open my app in a small window from universal link , do some work and dismiss window.